# Angular - Bind directive value to controller object

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive, binding

I'm trying to pass an array from a controller to a directive and for some (probably obvious to you lot!) reason when the array values are updated in the controller it does not reflect in the directive.  The controller obtains data from a service into an array and I want to pass that array to the directive to create a bar graph.  I've put the key parts of the code below.

Here is my top level HTML

```
<div dash-progress
    graph-data="{{dashCtrl.myProgress}}">
</div>
<div>
    Other Stuff
</div>
```

My template HTML for the directive:

```
<div class="boxcontent" ng-show="dashCtrl.showProgress">
    <div class="chart-holder-lg">
        <canvas tc-chartjs-bar
            chart-data="progress"
            chart-options="options"
            height="200"
            auto-legend>
        </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('dashCtrl',['mySvc',
    function(mySvc) {

        var self = this;
        this.myProgress = [];

        this.getProgress = function() {
            //logic must be in the service !
            mySvc.getProgress().then(function(success) {
                self.myProgress = mySvc.progress;
            });
        };
    }]);
```

and the directive:

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.directive('dashProgress', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: 'components/dashboard/progress.html',
        scope: {
            graphData: '@'
            },
        link: function(scope,el,attrs) {
            scope.progress = {
                labels: ['Duration','Percent'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                    label: 'Duration',
                    data: [scope.graphData.duration]
                    },
                    {
                    label: 'Percent',
                    data: [scope.graphData.percent]
                    }                        
                ]
            };
            scope.options = { };
        }
    }        
}]);
```

If I set an initial values of the `myProgress` object in the controller then these do get reflected in the directive, but I don't get the real values that I need when they are returned to the controller from the service.

Answer (score 0):

In your directive's scope, instead of this:

```
scope: {
  graphData: '@'
}
```

try using this:

```
scope: {
  graphData: '='
}
```

Comment: I only need one way binding and changing to '=' doesn't make any difference.  I've tried each type of scope config but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: You could try to call $scope.$digest() so that the directives are compiled again

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `{{ }}` when passing array to the directive with `=`. It will render the array in the view instead of passing a reference to directive's scope.
2. As far as I know, `@` is not only one-way binding, but also one-time binding and should be used mostly for string values (e.g. setting an html attribute while initializing directive). If you'd like to use `@`, you should firstly convert data to JSON, then pass it to directive with `{{ }}`, then parse it again in directive and after any change - manually recompile the directive. But it would be a little **overkill**, wouldn't it?

**Conclusion**

Just remove the curly brackets from the view and use `=` to bind value to directive's scope.

*View*

```
<div dash-progress
    graph-data="dashCtrl.myProgress">
</div>
```

*Directive*

```
scope: {
    graphData: '='
},
```

---

**Update**

Try one more thing. In `dashCtrl`, wrap `myProgress` with an object (you can change names to be more self-explaining - this is just an example):

```
this.graphData = {
    myProgress: []
}

this.getProgress = function() {
    mySvc.getProgress().then(function(success) {
        self.graphData.myProgress = mySvc.progress;
    });
}
```

Then, pass `graphData` to directive:

```
<div dash-progress
    graph-data="dashCtrl.graphData">
</div>
```

Finally, substitute every `scope.graphData` with `scope.graphData.myProgress`. This way you make sure that `scope.graphData.myProgress` always refers to the same data because it's a property of an object.

If this still doesn't work, you will probably have to use a watcher and update properties of `scope.progress` manually.

Comment: I seem to have tried about every possible combination, and if I set an initial value of `myProgress` in the controller it passes successfully to the directive, however it does not pass the updated value when the controller makes the call to the service.  I confirmed that the controller is receiving the right values, but they just don't seem to pass to the directive - could it be the way I am setting `myProgress` when the value is returned by the service call?

Comment: I've now put a watch on graphData in the directive and that picks up the value change, so there's some progress, but not yet updating the graph

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try one more workaround which I mentioned and tell me if there is any progress. As you said, it might be the problem with way of setting `myProgress`, because by using `=` you substitute an array with a new one.

Comment: Thanks @PJDev, seems it is updating in the directive now, but still something funny going on as I can reference the top level object (and see the properties) but cannot reference any properties directly

Comment: I'm not sure if I correctly get what you mean. Could you update your question to give more details about the issue?

Comment: basically if I `console.log(scope.graphData)` in the directive I see the object including the `myProgress` property containing my array, but if I `console.log(scope.graphData.myProgress)` then I get `undefined`

Comment: Well, that sounds pretty strange - I think I've never had such issue. I came accross a similar (but not the same) issue. When I used arrays which had custom indexes (e.g. string indexes instead of standard 0, 1, 2...), console.log displayed an empty array although it contained items. However, I've never got `undefined`, so it's hard to tell what's causing that. Did you try to use the data (event if it's undefined) to display the graph? And last question - could you provide a plunker with the code? It would be easier to investigate what's wrong.